# Zone.current.get function error in Angular 16.1.5

Tags: angular, zone, angular16, zone.js

[image: error in console]Multiple refresh in angular application leading to grey screen.  And giving the below error

Angular: 16.1.5
Zone: 0.13.0

I tired continuous browser refresh. After 4-5 refresh got the grey screen in my angular application. Navigation went back to the base url of application. Then one more refresh, it redirected to login screen of my application